# Входной буфер и вопросы относительно него

Tags: c++

я недавно начал заниматься программированием самостоятельно. Поэтому, извините если задам глупый вопрос. Недавно увидел такую строчку кода:

std::cout << "Input a keyboard character: "; // предположим, что пользователь ввел abcd

```
char ch;
std::cin >> ch; // ch = 'a', "bcd" останется во входном буфере
std::cout << ch << " has ASCII code " << static_cast<int>(ch) << std::endl;

// Обратите внимание, следующий cin не просит пользователя что-либо ввести, данные берутся из входного буфера!
std::cin >> ch; // ch = 'b', "cd" останется в буфере
std::cout << ch << " has ASCII code " << static_cast<int>(ch) << std::endl;
```

Что такое и как именно берутся данные из входного буфера? Есть ли какая-либо схема? Почему cin в данном случае не запрашивает? И, хотелось бы поподробнее, так как данная функция показалась мне полезной. И обязательно ли мне каждый раз говорить, что я недавно начал этим заниматься? Или можно открыто спрашивать?

Comment: Примерно так: Ентер нажат, и 4 символа отправились в поток cin.

Comment: [Что такое поток (stream)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435675)

Comment: [Буферизация данных в С](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1133936)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8